# Fastify validate schema with yup - schema.validateSync is not a function

Tags: yup, fastify

From the Fastify [documentation](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/) in the section titled `Using other validation libraries` I'm trying to get yup to validate my schema but I keep getting `schema.validateSync is not a function` and I don't know why??

I want the schema to still be valid for creating the swagger document but I want to use yup to give me the validation I need.

```js
const yup = require("yup");

const yupOptions = {
  strict: false,
  abortEarly: false,
  stripUnknown: true,
  recursive: true,
};

async function isUsernameAvailable(fastify: any, _options: Object) {
  const users = fastify.mongo.db.collection("users");

  fastify.get(
    "/api/v1/onboarding/isUsernameAvailable/:username",
    {
      schema: {
        params: {
          type: "object",
          properties: {
            username: { type: "string", maxLength: 12, minLength: 1 },
          },
          required: ["username"],
        },
        response: {
          200: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
              available: {
                type: "boolean",
                description: "Returns true if username is available",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      validatorCompiler: ({ schema, method, url, httpPart }: any) => {
        return function (data: any) {
          try {
            const result = schema.validateSync(data, yupOptions);
            return { value: result };
          } catch (e) {
            return { error: e };
          }
        };
      },
    },

    async (request: any, _reply: any) => {
      const { username } = request.params;
      const foundNUsernames = await users.countDocuments(
        { username },
        { limit: 1 }
      );
      const available: boolean = foundNUsernames === 0;
      return { available };
    }
  );
}

export { isUsernameAvailable };
```

if I use the below, the validation works but the swagger doc doesn't build

```js
schema: {
    params: yup.object({
    username: yup.string().lowercase().max(12).min(1).required(),
    }),
}
```

if I remove the `validatorCompiler` then I get no errors, swagger does build but I cant use yup

```js
 validatorCompiler: ({ schema, method, url, httpPart }: any) => {
        return function (data: any) {
          try {
            const result = schema.validateSync(data, yupOptions);
            return { value: result };
          } catch (e) {
            return { error: e };
          }
        };
      },
    }
```

how can I satisfy both?

Why do I want to use yup? I want to validate emails and transform values into lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at how [Zod](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Type-Providers#zod) does the process. According to the plugin you need to fulfill 3 requirements:

- [Type provider](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Type-Providers) see [Zod data type provider](https://github.com/turkerdev/fastify-type-provider-zod/blob/main/src/index.ts#L19) **done**
- [Validator compiler](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization#schema-validator) see [Zod validator compiler](https://github.com/turkerdev/fastify-type-provider-zod/blob/main/src/index.ts#L91) **done** but you could use async instead with [yup.validate](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemavalidatevalue-any-options-object-promiseinfertypeschema-validationerror)
- [Serializer compiler](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/#serializer-compiler) (missing) see [Zod JSON schema transform](https://github.com/turkerdev/fastify-type-provider-zod/blob/main/src/index.ts#L87C27-L87C27)

So based on what you have complete I might say you are ready 2/3 only missing to add the JSON schema transformer. For this step you might find useful this package [@sodaru/yup-to-json-schema](https://github.com/sodaru/yup-to-json-schema)

Edit:
I've published a package [fastify-type-provider-yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-type-provider-yup) so feel free to test it out.